# How to determine file type from kernel module?

Tags: c, kernel-module

Is there something like `struct dirent* -> d_type` that contains `DT_REG`, `DT_DIR`, `DT_SOCK` and etc. for kernel structures, for example for `struct file`? Looking at its fields, I cant find anything for this purpose.

Maybe someone knows how `readdir` determines `d_type`? I am looking at its implementation here https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/dirent/readdir.c and I cant understand what is going here.

Ubuntu18.04, 4.15.0-45 kernel version

Comment: What is the actual and real problem you need to solve? Why do you need such a field?

Comment: My actual and real problem is to determine types of files opened by some process (I have its `struct task_struct`) and count them like "3 regular files, 1 socket, 1 pipe"

Comment: What OS?  You've left that out, and it's somewhat important...

Comment: Are you looking for [`stat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)? If the files are already open, use `fstat()`.

Comment: Ah, you mean some _other_ process than the current one? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, for other process, not current. Thanks for mentioning `stat`, it could help me in some other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`struct inode` field `i_mode`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L603) is a bit-field that can be checked using the standard `S_ISDIR`, `S_ISREG`, `S_ISLNK` *et al* macros:

```
/*
 * Keep mostly read-only and often accessed (especially for
 * the RCU path lookup and 'stat' data) fields at the beginning
 * of the 'struct inode'
 */
struct inode {
    umode_t         i_mode;
    unsigned short      i_opflags;
    kuid_t          i_uid;
    kgid_t          i_gid;
       .
       .
       .
```

[An example of its use in ext4 kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext4/inode.c#L147):

```
/*
 * Test whether an inode is a fast symlink.
 * A fast symlink has its symlink data stored in ext4_inode_info->i_data.
 */
int ext4_inode_is_fast_symlink(struct inode *inode)
{
    if (!(EXT4_I(inode)->i_flags & EXT4_EA_INODE_FL)) {
        int ea_blocks = EXT4_I(inode)->i_file_acl ?
                EXT4_CLUSTER_SIZE(inode->i_sb) >> 9 : 0;

        if (ext4_has_inline_data(inode))
            return 0;

        return (S_ISLNK(inode->i_mode) && inode->i_blocks - ea_blocks == 0);
    }
    return S_ISLNK(inode->i_mode) && inode->i_size &&
           (inode->i_size < EXT4_N_BLOCKS * 4);
}
```

Note that you need to be really careful traversing such kernel structures.  If you don't take the proper locks, they can change out from under the thread examining them.